# How to move / align X-axis title on multiple charts with Altair?

Tags: title, altair, x-axis

I have the 3 charts below and I would like to vertically align the X-axis title of the third chart ("Autres") with the two others

[image]

My code is the following

```
...
base = alt.Chart(data).properties(
    width=250,
    height=250
).add_selection(selector)
base2 = alt.Chart(data.loc[data.time.isin(l1)]).properties(
    width=250,
    height=250
).add_selection(selector)
base3 = alt.Chart(data.loc[data.time.isin(l2)]).properties(
    width=250,
    height=250
).add_selection(selector)

points = base.mark_point(filled=True, size=50,opacity=1).encode(
    x=alt.X('trage',title="Tranche d'âge"),
    y=alt.Y('mean(y)',title='NBV (%CA)',axis=alt.Axis(format='%')),
    color=alt.condition(selector, 'Reseau_pat:O', alt.value('lightgray')),
    #shape=alt.Shape('Segment:O', scale=alt.Scale(range=['circle', 'triangle'])),
    tooltip = ['id','x','mean(y)']
)

timeseries = base2.mark_bar(opacity=1).encode(
    x=alt.X('time', title='Structure de marge (%PM)'),
    y=alt.Y('value',title='', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(-1, 1)),stack=None,axis=alt.Axis(format='.2f')),
    #y2=alt.Y2('mean(duree)'),
    color=alt.Color('Reseau_pat:O',
                    scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_),
                    #legend=None
                   ),
    tooltip = ['value']
).transform_filter(
    selector
)

test = base3.mark_bar(opacity=1,size=50).encode(
    y=alt.Y('time', title='',axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
    x=alt.X('value', title="Autres",scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 40)),stack=None),
    color=alt.Color('Reseau_pat:O',
                    scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_),
                    #legend=None
                   ),
    tooltip = ['value']
).transform_filter(
    selector
)

points | timeseries | test
```

If you have any idea, it would be very apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually shift the title by using the `titleY` and `titleX` argument in the Axis. Do this for all plots, using the same value and they align. So something like  `x=alt.X(...axis=alt.Axis(titleY=42)`.

You could also opt for adding a title to each plot using `.properties(title='Autres')` and remove the x-axis title. Then the titles would align (on top) at least.